# Issue with Autoscaling SVG Parts in Flutter: Seeking Help for Proportional Expansion within Parent Container

Tags: flutter

I've developed a widget that allows each part of an SVG human body to be highlighted. However, I am facing a single issue. I wish to achieve autoscaling for all the SVG parts based on the parent's height and size. For instance, if a container has the HumanAI widget as its child and it expands in width, I want the collection of SVGs to widen proportionally, ensuring it stretches with the container. Currently, the SVGs either remain hidden or are positioned in the left corner.

Here is the code:

https://pastebin.com/i0wJAVQe

`must type here else wont let me post`

I've tried alignment at center and adjusted various scaling parameters on the matrix4 etc